# How to render json with JBuilder in Rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, ruby-on-rails-3, jbuilder

I'm trying to integrate JBuilder into Rails 3.2 project.  I've installed the gem, and I've written a JBuilder file at `app/views/books/index.json.jbuilder`.

Here's my index action:

```
  def index

    @books = Book.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @books }
    end
  end
```

This seems to call the default `as_json` method of `Book` to render the response. What do I need to change to tell Rails to use my JBuilder template instead?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Remove the block you're passing to `format.json`. You're causing it to ignore your jbuilder file and instead return the result of `json: @books` as a response. If you leave the block out:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html # index.html.erb
  format.json # no block here
end
```

Then Rails will fall back to its default handling of the response and look for a template in your view directory, it'll find the jbuilder file and render that as the response.

Comment: not working I'm in a jquery ajax call using json format and it tries to find the html view